# `ERROR: EOFError: read end of file` when using package after installing new Julia version

Tags: package, julia

I just installed Julia `v1.3.1` (previously had `v1.3.0` installed) and when I try `using ODBC`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: EOFError: read end of file
Stacktrace:
 [1] read(::IOStream, ::Type{Int64}) at .\iostream.jl:361
 [2] parse_cache_header(::IOStream) at .\loading.jl:1334
 [3] stale_cachefile(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1413
 [4] _require_search_from_serialized(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:752
 [5] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:1001
 [6] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:922
 [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:917
```

I tried `rm ODBC` and then adding it again, as well as removing the `Manifest.toml` and `Project.toml` from my `v1.3` environment folder and freshly `add`-ing it .

Comment: For anyone who got here from Google, the same error message can result from calling `popfirst!` on an empty iterator (in Julia 1.10, at least).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia is failing to read the precompiled file of `ODBC` or of one of its dependencies, you can tell that from the stacktrace (`read` call in `parse_cache_header` function).  This likely means that this is corrupted.  You can fix the issue by deleting the precompiled files for the package for version 1.3 in the `~/.julia/compiled/v1.3/ODBC` directory.  If that fails, you should try removing the precompiled files for all of its dependencies, but in that case is probably easier to remove all directories in the `~/.julia/compiled/v1.3` directory.